# CS50 Blur filter gave incorrect outputs with small test cases

Tags: c, image-processing, convolution, cs50

I am writing the mean blur filter for the filter task in CS50 (more comfortable version). When I tested it with some my pictures, it seemed to work fine. However, when I tested it with CS50 test cases, it gave wrong results for small matrices. Below is my code

```c
#define KERNEL_HEIGHT 3
#define KERNEL_WIDTH 3
#define KERNEL_SIZE 9
#define CORNER 4
#define EDGE 6
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // height and width are the height and width of the input image.
    RGBTRIPLE(*extension)[width + 2] = calloc(height + 2, (width + 2) * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)); // I will handle edge and corner cases by creating a new 2d array with 0s around 
    RGBTRIPLE(*newImage)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)); //output 
    int cof = 0, redSum = 0, greenSum = 0, blueSum = 0;
    int kernel[3][3] = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}; // Kernel for mean blur
    if (newImage == NULL || extension == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory to create a new image.\n");
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(extension[i + 1], image[i], sizeof(image[i])); // Copy values from original images into extension, note that I intentionally copy at the i + 1 position.
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < height + 1; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < width + 1; ++j)
        {
            redSum = 0; greenSum = 0; blueSum = 0; //Reset red, green, blue sum values.
            for(int k = 0; k < KERNEL_HEIGHT; ++k)
            {
                for(int t = 0; t < KERNEL_WIDTH; ++t) 
                {
                    cof = kernel[k][t]; // I will multiply each value in the kernel with the pixel value and its neighbors.
                    redSum += cof * extension[i - 1 + k][j - 1 + t].rgbtRed;
                    greenSum += cof * extension[i - 1 + k][j - 1 + t].rgbtGreen;
                    blueSum += cof * extension[i - 1 + k][j - 1 + t].rgbtBlue;
                }
            }
            if(i == 1 || i == height) // Detecting edge cases and corner
            {
                if(j == 1 || j == width) // Corner
                {
                    newImage[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = (int) round((float) redSum / (float) CORNER);
                    newImage[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen = (int) round((float) greenSum / (float) CORNER);
                    newImage[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue = (int) round((float) blueSum / (float) CORNER);
                }
                else // Edges
                {
                    newImage[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = (int) round((float) redSum / (float) EDGE);
                    newImage[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen = (int) round((float) greenSum / (float) EDGE);
                    newImage[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue = (int) round((float) blueSum / (float) EDGE);
                }
            }
            else //Normal cases
            {
                newImage[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = (int) round((float) redSum / (float) KERNEL_SIZE);
                newImage[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen = (int) round((float) greenSum / (float) KERNEL_SIZE);
                newImage[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue = (int) round((float) blueSum / (float) KERNEL_SIZE);
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(image[i], newImage[i], sizeof(newImage[i])); // Copy back the results into my original image.
    }
    free(extension);
    free(newImage);
    return;
}
```

And this is one of the test case:
testing with sample 3x3 image(Filtering middle pixel)
first row: (10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60), (70, 80, 90)
second row: (110, 130, 140), (120, 140, 150), (130, 150, 160)
third row: (200, 210, 220), (220, 230, 240), (240, 250, 255)

Expected output: 127 140 149
Actual output: 91 100 106

I have been trying to fix this this function( gg search, reading documents) several days and still no result. I think it has to do with how I allocate memory for the extension matrix and how I traverse through it. I am pretty new to dynamic memory allocation so maybe that's the part where I got wrong.

Comment: I fixed my code a little bit by changing my index interval for i and j. Previously, it only gave me 0s, now it does not give me 0s anymore but still incorrect results.

Comment: The kernel matrix may seem pointless because its proponent are all 1s anyway, but I wrote it so I can use it in another part of the program which I will write later.

Comment: I don’t know how `RGBTRIPLE` is defined, but I guess it’s 8 bit? Are you normalizing your data correctly so there’s no overflow? Are you defining your input image in the right storage order?

Comment: 1. You can use 1 memcpy for your whole 2D array.  2. Edge of image cases will over weigh towards 0 with your solution.  On the edge, just include the pixels in range, not a bunch of extra zeroes which will "dim" the outside of your image - thankfully you don't use that edge structure...  3. Your indexing is too complex.  I'd add asserts to each to make sure you are not reading off the edge of an array.  As it is, I am almost 100% certain you are reading out of bounds with your loops starting at 1 and going to size + 1 - Get the loops right and you don't need all the -1s.

Comment: one thing to remember:  in C, array indexes are in the range: 0...(number of entries in array -1 )   Not 1...number of entries in array.

Comment: Yes I know that array indexes start at 0, I just wanted to create 2 column full of 0s at the beginning and the end of the matrix to handle edge and corner cases (hence why I started at 1). However, I did realize it was not a good strategy, I followed Dorgan answer and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to do this and will revisit when I have more time but...  below is yet untested and purposely incomplete - used as a style guide only.

I am going to post most of a BlurPixel() to show you how you could handle each pixel in a logical manner.  Notice, we don't have crazy indexing and that every write is being bounds checked by the if statement.

```
      int r=0, g=0, b=0;  // Sums accumulators
      int numElements = 0; // Counts number of items accumulated.

      // Loop from 1 less to 1 more than the current X and Y position.
      for(int xOffset=-1; xOffset<=1; xOffset++)
      {
        for(int yOffset=-1; yOffset<=1; yOffset++)
        {
          const int newX = x + xOffset;
          const int newY = y + yOffset;

          // Bounds check... 
          if(newX >= 0 && newX < width &&
             newY >= 0 && newY < height) 
          {
            // In range, add to accumulators and increment element counter.
            r += image[newY][newX].red;
            g += image[newY][newX].green;
            b += image[newY][newX].blue;
            numElements++;
          }
        }
      }  

      // Assign the rounded values to the new structure.  Could do this with integers
      // if we added numElements/2 to list before divide.
      newImage[j][i].red = (int)round((float) r / numElements);
      newImage[j][i].green = (int)round((float) g / numElements);
      newImage[j][i].blue = (int)round((float) b / numElements);
```

Comment: I realized I wrote my code over-complicated with all those indexing and that extension matrix. Anyway I juts changed your if statement to """ (newX >= 0 && newX < width) && (newY >= 0 && newY < height)) """ and it worked. Your answer just helped me to delete most of my unnecessary codes in my program. Thank you very much.

Comment: If statements inside loops like this tend to slow down code significantly (order of magnitude slower sometimes). OP's concept of extending the image and adding the "+1" in the indexing is sound, as it removes the need for conditionals. Unfortunately OP added other conditionals to change the division, which seems unnecessary to me and nulls the speed gain.

Comment: Correctness first.  Speed 2nd always.  As I stated, this was more about showing him how to fix his wonky indexing rather than an optimized example. This was for a 1st year CS student :)  If we cared more about speed, then yes, we specialize the loops so that the checks are not needed, we copy structures at a time (I/O is almost always where the real slowdown occurs), and we perhaps use SIMD and even parallel/thread work as well if it makes sense.